# Mark all images in Grid View of Android

Tags: android, gridview

I am re using code mentioned at tutorial http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/android-custom-gallery-and-instant-upload-project/

In this project, How can I add mark all checkbox besides select button?
So that it will mark all checkboxes in thumbnails and then i can click select so it will select all thumbnails…
Can someone please help me with this ?

I posted same comment below the post also but looks like author has not noticed it. So asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check all images automatically after on one button click you need to just change the values of each item of images arraylist's value to true.

```
 **public ArrayList<ImageItem> images = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();**
```

As in the initialize method of adapter you are preparing the whole arraylist from media just do that but to select all images check box change the selection value of each ImageItem in arraylist to true and just call this method **adapter.notifydatasetchanged()**. This will surely work.